# How do I go about finding the derivative of this

Tags: calculus

I'm looking to find the derivative of :

$$x\cos x \sin x$$

So it's a product rule inside a product rule ?

$$f(x) = x ,g(x) = \cos x $$

$$f'(x)= 1, g'(x)=-\sin x$$

Then,

$$ (1 \bullet \cos x) + (x  \bullet -\sin x ) $$ 
$$ \cos x + -x\sin x $$

Would that by my $f'(x)$ ?

And then for $g'(x)$ I do the product rule of $\cos x \sin x $ ?

Or if this is completely wrong could someone point me in the direction I should go in.

Comment: You can use $(fgh)'=f'gh+fg'h+fgh'.$

Comment: To clarify the comment from @mfl: use the product rule twice. This gives $$(fgh)'=([fg]h)'=[fg]'h+[fg]h'$$ $$=[f'g+fg']h +[fg]h'=f'gh +fg'h +fgh'$$ So there's no need to memorize this form just group and apply the product rule twice as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would recast it as $\frac{1}{2}x\sin 2x$ using the double angle sine identity so that you need only apply product rule once (and a very simple application of chain rule).

So the derivative is $\frac{1}{2}(x \cdot 2\cos 2x + \sin 2x) = x\cos 2x + \frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$.

Of course, you can also apply product rule in turn for each of the three "terms" without using a trig identity:

$$(x\cos x \sin x)' = (x)'\cos x \sin x + x(\cos x)'(\sin x) + x(\cos x)(\sin x)' = \cos x \sin x - x \sin^2 x + x\cos^2 x$$

Using the cosine and sine double angle formulas, you can recognise that the above can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x + x\cos 2x$$

which is exactly what I got before using the other method.

Take home message: always aim to simply (algebraically, trigonometrically, using laws of exponents/logs, etc.) before differentiating. You might find it simplifies your work significantly.

Answer (score 1):

$$(fgh)^\prime = (f(gh))^\prime = f(gh)^\prime + f^\prime(gh) = f(gh^\prime + g^\prime h) + f^\prime gh = fgh^\prime + fg^\prime h + f^\prime gh$$

Now write $f(x) = x$, $g(x)= \cos x$, $h(x) = \sin x$.